# How can i convert the tabular into longtable

Tags: longtable

I have this report and I can be as long as 40 pages. My current setting is cutting it on one page only.

I am very new to latex and I am just copy pasting from internet. If you guys can fix that.

This is the working copy of that

https://www.writelatex.com/174546bmvnqt

```
\subsection{Current Students}
\begin{table}[H]
  \caption{Current Objects }
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{*{4}{|p{4cm}}{|p{7cm}}}
    \hline\hline
    \rowcolor{orange}  
    Proponent                     &Statutory Process        &Student Name                 &Student Region          &Subjects\\
    \hline\hline
    Nevertheless, the natural ... &EP Act Environmental ... &With this clarification, ... &[uNorthwest Transition] &
      \begin{tabular}{*{1}{|p{0.5cm}}{|p{6cm}}}
        \hline\hline
        \rowcolor{orange}
        \# &Subject Type      \\
        \hline
        \rowcolor{white}
        1 &Research           \\\hline
        2 &Restoration        \\\hline
        3 &Research           \\\hline
        4 &Land aquisition    \\\hline
        5 &Onground management\\\hline
      \end{tabular}\\
    \hline
    Of course, the ...            &EP Act Clearing ...      &Of course, the ...           &[uGibson Desert]        &
      \begin{tabular}{*{1}{|p{0.5cm}}{|p{6cm}}}
        \hline\hline
        \rowcolor{orange}
        \# &Subject Type      \\
        \hline
        \rowcolor{white}
        1 &Education          \\\hline
        2 &Land aquisition    \\\hline
        3 &Subject funds      \\\hline
        4 &Other              \\\hline
        5 &Restoration        \\\hline
        6 &Recovery plans     \\\hline
        7 &Subject funds      \\\hline
      \end{tabular}
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: Also, for the future, please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that starts with `\documentclass{...}`, ends with `\end{document}` and is verified to compile / produce the error you need help with.  It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is :)

Comment: @Xavier I have MWE in the link provided above

Comment: The "M" of MWE stands for "minimal"...

Comment: @Xavier , i have made that minimal

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention in my answer that you also need to get rid of the surrounding `table` environment and put the caption inside the `longtable`. I've edited my answer as well as your code on sharelatex.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To use `longtable`, add this to your preamble

```
\usepackage{longtable}
```

and then replace every `\begin{tabular}` by `\begin{longtable}` and `\end{tabular}` by `\end{longtable}`.

You also need to get rid of any surrounding `table` environment, and push an eventual caption inside the `longtable`.

Comment: Can you please make chnage here because i am not getting it to work https://www.writelatex.com/174546bmvnqt

Comment: thanks buddy , that worked. One last thing if you can help me. How can i add the timeand date on the top righthand side corner in small font on first page. Like generated on bla bla

Comment: @user17 Just do a search for `fancyhdr` on this site :)